# setting NSTextField text as bold using xib in Mac App

Tags: cocoa-touch, macos

I need to set my NSTextField text as bold using  xib.Pleas help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the NSTextField and in Interface Builder, select the Font menu. This will open the Font manager.

Here whatever font, font size and property (bold, italic, regular etc) you will select will be reflected in your NSTextField.